# a left padding appears in crhomium when using flex; but not in firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend, chromium

i am using Manjaro as an OS so i don't know about Chrome.
i have this issue where a padding appears on the left after using flexbox, this issue only happened in Chromium and not in firefox.

i don't know where the problem is (as i don't know if there's any problem with the code at all apart from accessibility and responsivenss but this is because i didn't finish coding yet)

**this is my html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />

    <title>Frontend Mentor | Stats preview card component</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="container">
      <div class="hero-image">
        <img src="./images/image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="" srcset="" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="main-header">
          Get <span>insights</span> that help your business grow.
        </div>
        <div>
          Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions
          regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>10k+</div>
            <div>companies</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>314</div>
            <div>templates</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>12m+</div>
            <div>queries</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

**this is the CSS**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.main-header {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

span {
  color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}
.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}
```

ps: this is a frontendMentor challenge!

Comment: Where is "padding on the left"? wich element gets this behaviour? is it just the container or more?

Comment: @RamondeVries yes the container; i think i solved it by adding ` justify-content: left;`.

Comment: @RamondeVries but i don't know why it only happened in chromium (maybe chrome too)

Comment: that shouldn't affect padding, justify-content is only to align the content, are you sure it shows as padding?

Comment: @RamondeVries it doesn't show as padding (because i reset the padding with *) but it looks like padding.

Comment: The content goes to the right because you have `.container{flex-direction: row-reverse;}`. Why do you use it?

Comment: @Azu yeah yeah, it was "easier" to deal with when it was on the left LOL, i think it's just because i am a begineer in using vanilla CSS, i usually just use a library/framework for the frontEnd!